# How to update with multi values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Teacher` (`TeacherID, value1, value2`)

I need to update value like this: I call `temptable` (`TeacherID, value1, value2`)

```
TeacherID  Value1 Value2
T01       | 9    | 9
T01       | 19   | 8
T02       | 10   | 10
```

Values need to update, it has 2 rows with the same `TeacherID`. I want the row for `T01` to have the new value of `19`.

I wrote the UPDATE like this:

```
update Teacher   
set  Teacher.value1 = proco.ProCoName,   
     Teacher.value2 = proco.Co    
from (select tempTechID, tempvalue1, tempvalue2 from temptable) tmp
where Teacher.TeacherID = tmp.tempTechID
```

But when I execute this SQL, value of the row with `TeacherID = T01` becomes 9

Can anyone help me? Thanks all.

Comment: How would your update know which values you want for `T01`? Is there any other column in `temptable`?

Comment: I mean, i want to update 2 times for 1 teacher with 2 values but I want update last value in temptable. Value T01 in Teacher table is :T01       | 19   | 8

Comment: And don't have any column in temptable

Comment: Acctually, I wrote store with parameters is xml data. temptable is xml data. Teacher table is that i want to update values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need rows to be unique on the criteria you are using in the where clause, otherwise you may update one or more rows you don't intend to.

EDIT: Added the code for the hack way.

```
update Teacher   
set Teacher.value1 = proco.ProCoName,   
    Teacher.value2 = proco.Co    
from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value1) [RN],
         teacherID, value1, value2
  FROM Teacher )
INNER JOIN (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tempvalue1) [TMPRN],
        tempTechID,tempvalue1,tempvalue2 
            from temptable) tmp
ON teacher.RN = tmp.TMPRN
```

Or you could build your temporary table to have the teacher ID and the previous two values, as well as the two new values then join it back on the previous values and set the columns to the new values.

```
INSERT INTO #tempData
SELECT teacherID, value1, value2, newvalue1, newvalue2
FROM teacher

UPDATE Teacher
SET value1 = newvalue1, value2 = newvalue2
FROM Teacher t
INNER JOIN #tempData td
ON t.teacherid = td.teacherID
AND t.value1 = td.value1
AND t.value2 = td.value2
```

Comment: I know and I used to do. If temptable only have one value for one teacherID,I will complete already. But if I want to do like this, Have any way can I do?

Comment: You could give both data sets a row_number and order by one of the value columns but that's a bit of a hack and not reliable for serious work.

Anyway, if you would like to try it Ive posted the code above ^

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe I should do old way, I used to.

Comment: See my post again, Ive added another way you can do it. This way is reliable but might take a bit of work to prepare.